# Windows form application - text Highlighting

Tags: c#

I am using a WFA which has a *ToolStripMenuItem* that is supposed to search for a word in a textBox and highlight it. This is the highlighting code.

first = first index to be highlighted
, length= number of characters to be highlighted.

```
            textBox2.SelectionStart = first;
            textBox2.SelectionLength = length;
            //scroll to the caret
            textBox2.ScrollToCaret();
```

everything seems to be working well. However, If the mouse cursor isn't inside textBox2 (say in another textBox). The highlighting doesn't work. Is there a way to make it work regardless of the position of the mouse cursor? in other words, is there a way to change my code to make it highlight the text in textBox2 even if the mouse cursor wasn't inside textBox2 before hitting the *ToolStripMenuItem*?

P.S. It's worth mentioning that I am using c# in VS 2010

Comment: try textBox2.Focus() before running your highlight code

Comment: Thanks! this is what I needed! Could you post this as an answer to mark it as a solution please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
textBox2.Focus();
```

before you run the code that highlights the text.  This will move input focus (and your cursor) to the textbox

Answer (score 0):

just use richtextbox and change the backcolor of the text.
this way you can use multiple highlights at a time and the highlight won't be lost after the user focus the textbox by mouseclick. Additionally you can save all postions and automatically select the textpart if the user clicks into the highlighted area.

you can also show the selection like LarsTech mentioned, but after the user clicks inside the textbox the selection will get lost.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Sadly, I am forced to use textBox and don't have the option of using RichtextBox